# Laravel SweetAlert2 - Block UI while Aajax request is sent

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a button that user clicks and asks him if he wants to proceed with request or not.
If he selects "OK", an AJAX request is sent to backend and when response is recieved, a new sweet alert is fired informing user that request has been executed succesfully or not.

The problem i'm having is that between the time the user confirms to send the request and the response is recieved, the UI is free for user for clicking again the button that fires the request.

If there any way to block UI while request is sent and/or closing the first sweetalert when response is recieved and fire the second sweetalert for informing user about request result?

This is the code:

```
"use strict";

function likeProperty(matchid) {

    swal.fire({
        buttonsStyling: false,
        text: "¿Esta seguro que desea enviar una notificación al agente informando que estás interesado en su propiedad?",
        type: "question",
        confirmButtonText: "Si, enviar!",
        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-sm btn-bold btn-brand",
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancelar",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-sm btn-bold btn-danger"

    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result.value) {

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/processes/offerdemand/matchlike/'+ matchid,
                data: {
                    'id': matchid,
                },
                dataType: 'JSON',

                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.status != 200) {

                        console.log(data.status);
                        swal.fire({
                            "title": "",
                            "text": "Ocurrió un error, contactar al administrador",
                            "type": "error",
                            showConfirmButton: !1,
                            timer: 3000,
                            onClose: () => {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    if (data.status = 200) {
                        swal.fire({
                            "title": "",
                            "text": "Se ha notificado al agente que estas interesado en su propiedad!",
                            "type": "success",
                            showConfirmButton: !1,
                            timer: 3000,
                            onClose: () => {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    // hide like button
                    $('#likeprop'+matchid).hide();
                    // show like button
                    $('#unlikeprop'+matchid).show();
                    // window.location.reload();
                    console.log(data);
                },
            })
            var xhr = $.ajax();
            console.log(xhr)

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at "queue"

Comment: Thanks @Chris
It looks "queue" is not what I'm needing, regards!